# Creating Python Code Installer Using Custom Directory

Tags: python, windows-installer

I was working with [distutils](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) and I wanted to see if it's possible to install my code to a custom folder outside the site-package folder in the python installation location.

My end goal is to just create a distribution of my program, not actually register it as a package or module.  That way when the program needs to be installed, it's easy.

I would want to place all my code in a folder called something like:

```
c:/myprogram  
   /src   
   /data_connections  
   ... etc other sub folders
```

Basic Environment Information:

- Python 2.7 32-bit
- Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 OS

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Py2Exe wich makes a exe program from your python script.
   Then you can use an install creator to make a single executable that will prompt you for install directory ect..

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it out.